How to handle picture editing in react native (expo)?
How do i go about creating an image editor in Expo? What libraries can i use to simplify this? The image has to be exportable as a file so i can send it to the backend. It should be able to crop images, add text etc.
Currently I overlay the Image With react 2d context. The overlay works well, but i would like to export this as a picture.
    <View
        className="absolute w-full h-full bg-gray-light "
        style={{ pointerEvents: "box-none" }}
      >
        <GLView
          className="relative"
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          onContextCreate={onGLContextCreate}
        />
      </View>
      <View className="w-full h-full absolute shrink-0">
        <Image
          source={{ uri: pictureFileLocation }}
          className="w-full h-full "
        />
      </View>


react-native-skia comes with some decent built in shaders, the ability to write text, and then the ability to take a snapshot of the canvas
